# How to crop and resize in the browser

Tags: css, html

I like to do a client side crop and resize of an image before displaying it in HTML 5. (The actual react application will allow to select a part of a bigger image that is displayed in a fixed size image window)

I know the offsets in pixels (x and y)  in the source image and the scaling factors for width and height needed.

I can easily crop (without scaling)

```
<div style="overflow:hidden; width:300; height:300;">
    <div style="display: inline-block; background: url('test.png') no-repeat; background-position: -10px, -10px;" />
</div>
```

Scaling works, but cropping get's corrupted when I include scaling

```
<div style="overflow:hidden; width:300; height:300;">
    <div style="display: inline-block; background: url('test.png') no-repeat; background-position: -10px, -10px; transform: scale(10, 10);" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the following solution

```
<div style="overflow: hidden; width: 300px; height: 300px;">
    <img src="test.png" style="width: 600px; height: 600px; transform: translateX(-300px) translateY(-300px);">
</div>
```

The important aspects are:

- Have a size limiting container (the div) with overflow: hidden
- Resize the complete image by scaling the width and height
- Crop the needed parts from the resized image (with transform translateX translateY)

Answer (score 0):

[CSS clip-path](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path) is a pretty versatile CSS property that does exactly what it sounds like you need to do. It can get lengthy, however, so I highly recommend moving to an external stylesheet as opposed to doing this inline.

What I would suggest is that you set the image in a fixed-size container, as you stated, set `overflow: hidden;` (of course), and crop the image with `clip-path`. For resizing it, use `transform: scale()` with one parameter, depending on how much you need to scale it.

Keep in mind that another rule could also be used like [CSS object-fit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit).

Comment: Clip path has the same problem for me: It works (as desired) without scaling. As soon as I add scalling, the cropped image part changes.

Comment: @RuedigerJungbeck, is it possible for you to apply the transform first and then work out the clip-path second, essentially hard-coding it? Or is this a case where you need to animate/switch between the two states?